# MBP 16": Relative ambient heat of i7 v. i9

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, temperature

So for me a very important aspect of devices is their ambient heat. I have an annoying kind of eczema that causes rashes on my hands/skin if I have sustained contact with something warm, and it can be triggered by computers etc.

I am wondering if anyone has numbers on how hot the i7 chips are compared to the i9's in the new MacBook Pro 16".

I bought the upgrade to get the cheaper i9 (2.3Ghz) and am finding the device very very warm even when the CPUs are just sitting there at 1-3% (and I'm in a cold wintery room, so the internal heat is overcoming the air outside too).

I don't know exactly what's making it so warm (iStat menus shows the batteries, palm rests, and thunderbolt ports as being the hottest parts), but am curious about how this computer would compare to the i7. I seriously considered buying the i7 just to have a cooler computer but the upgrade was cheap enough and I wanted the better GPU so I went for it.

If it turns out the i7 **IS** significantly cooler than this i9, I might trade it in for the sake of my long-term skin health.

**So the question again: Is there data out there about the relative ambient and under-load temperatures of the i7 v. i9 versions of the MacBook Pro. If so, is the i7 meaningfully cooler under normal circumstances.**

Comment: Try disabling turbo boost or hyper-threading to reduce heat. See: http://tbswitcher.rugarciap.com ; https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210108

Comment: Yeah, thanks, that's something I haven't looked in to yet, but certainly an option if I had a light workload on a hot day and the ambient temperature was giving me problems. The performance hit would be huge though, so I'm still interested in the difference between the i7 and i9 when all their features are enabled. .

Comment: These chipsets are so powerful and fast that disabling TuboBoost doesn't really impact performance. I've just installed TurboBoost Switcher in a new MBP 16 Catalina (been using it for years on multiple 2011 MBP i7) and fan noise just dropped by two-thirds. I.e. I can get the fans going with parallel photo processing but it takes longer and noise dies faster. When processing photos one at a time, the fans don't turn on any more. With Turbo Boost, exporting even a single photo was one enough to get the fans going loud and they took a long time to shut off.